# An arbitrary reputation score pops up periodically

Tags: bug, reputation

I've just noticed a bug on Stack Exchange (particularly on Stack Overflow and [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour)) - an arbitrary rep score is popping up on my rep score icon, while I don't have that increase.

Here's the screenshot:

[image]

That's pretty annoying and confusing ... Would that be fixed?

Comment: it's not fixed from that time

Comment: Is that a question? No, it has not yet been fixed.

Comment: If I have worked at SO - I would fixed that long ago ...

Comment: @Roman pretty sure they'll contact you soon enough so you can fix it for all of us.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest: Please apply!

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest That's replication, fixing a bug of unknown origin, moving it to a test server, extensive testing to make sure it doesn't cause new bugs in production, an upgrade without downtime on a site with millions of users, all in two weeks, and all by you? I'm sure you're getting lots of job offers then.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth Don't get all these snarky comments whenever there is a critique of SO. All of us are programmers, some of us are actually good. The original bug is from 1.5 half month ago. More then enough time to fix it. This looks like something trivial, not currently looking for a job but I can guarantee that I will fix it in 45 days for $20,000 so I'm applying. For somebody who  actually works for SO and knows the code base it shouldn't take more than a day, two days tops.

Comment: @Oleg My point is that, as a programmer, you only have so much influence. The process to get a fix live takes time. You can't just say _"Oh, I could fix that in a day, easy!"_ when working with a site with millions of users. Most of the delay likely isn't caused by the programmers.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth, it's not even about programming ... When I said *I would fixed that long ago* - that also means that If I was given an authorities as a manager - I would "kick" those guys that wasting the "fixing" time on my site

Comment: @Roman, it would be great to have you in charge of this and any other projects.

Comment: if you would work at SO you'd spend all of your time working on [how to recognise when two posts are falsely labeled as duplicates](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/296357/165773) or [rehashing top bar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/301845/165773), stuff like that

Comment: @gnat, I'm not working at SO, so you don't know how would I spend my time ...